# Update nested resource in Rails changing its parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nested-attributes

I have an very specific scenario in my application where the user have to asign REGIONS to a TERRITORY.

So in my routes file I declared the nested resource:

```
resource Territory
    resource Region
end
```

And in the Territory model I have:

```
class Territory
   has_many :regions, :dependent => :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :regions
end
```

For this case I need the user to be able to re-asign regions between territories just by updating the territory_id in the region model.

So, if I create a territory called "East" and then assign the regions "New York" and "New Jersey" to it, I should be able to create another territory and then assign "New York" to it and the application should only change the territory_id of the region to the new one.

All the logic is in the territories controller (I actually don't have a regions controller), there's a small static set of possible regions (Spanish provinces) and the user can add or remove regions when editing a territory. What I need is that, when the user adds a region to a territory and this region was already assigned to another territory, instead of creating a new region, I'd like rails to change the territory_id of the region.

Whenever I try to do it I get the following error:

Couldn't find Region with ID=101 for Territory with ID=14

Any help?

Answer (score -2):

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :territory
end
```

---

```
old_territory = Territory.create :name => "East"
new_territory = Territory.create :name => "other"
new_york = old_territory.regions.create :name => "New York"
new_york.update_attributes :territory => new_territory
```

Comment: That's not what I need. I control the association of territories and regions in the territories controller. For example, when the user edits a territories he can add or remove regions from it.